# How to import OpenSSL in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl

I am trying to run this simple code to retrieve SSL certificate:

```
import ssl, socket

#print ssl.get_server_certificate(('www.google.com', 443))
cert=ssl.get_server_certificate(('www.google.com', 443))
# OpenSSL
x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
x509.get_subject().get_components()
```

But I get error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e\Desktop\Python\ssl\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
NameError: name 'OpenSSL' is not defined
```

I am aware that I have to import OpenSSL. But I do not know how? and where to get the OpenSSL from? 
I downloaded a module called pyOpenSSL from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL
Which contains two folders: pyOpenSSL-0.15.1.dist-info and OpenSSL.
When I tried to add import OpenSSL or import pyOpenSSL I get errors. 
Can you explain clearly please, how to import these libraries or modules? where they should be placed? if not in the same directory of my code file? how to write the path in the import syntax??
Please, help.

**EDIT:**
when tried to add `from OpenSSL import SSL` in the code, I got:

```
    C:\Users\e\Desktop\Python\ssl>test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e\Desktop\Python\ssl\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL
  File "C:\Users\e\Desktop\Python\ssl\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "C:\Users\e\Desktop\Python\ssl\OpenSSL\rand.py", line 9, in <module>
    from six import integer_types as _integer_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

Comment: pip install six or pip install requests[security]

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From the [tests](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/master/examples/SecureXMLRPCServer.py):

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
```

Response to the edit: `pip install pyopenssl` should have installed six. If you're trying to install yourself, I'd not do this, but you can install the dependencies manually using `pip install six cryptography` and then your import should work fine. If not, leave a comment and I'll do some further investigation.

Response to comment: There are instructions on [installing pip on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

Comment: I am a windows user. I tried the command but I get: " 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @user2192774, please type 'python -m pip install pyopenssl'.

Answer (score 0):

Both these forms works.

```
import OpenSSL.SSL  # or
from OpenSSL import SSL
```

You can also install using conda.

Please be aware that there are two python packages of similar names: openssl and pyopenssl.

- Both has the same import name OpenSSL
- Both are being used by many other packages. So it is not one supersede the other. Both are needed in general.
- Install pyopenssl looks like will install openssl too.
- For example, python itself uses openssl, while conda uses pyopenssl.

Here are the code snipes to see:

```
conda create -n x1 python=3.8 
conda list -n x1 | grep openssl # will see openssl
```