# ssl.get_server_certificate for sites with SNI (Server Name Indication)

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, sni

I am trying to get the server certificate of badssl.com subdomains (ex. https://expired.badssl.com).

```
import ssl
ssl.get_server_certificate(('expired.badssl.com', 443))
```

But when examining the above generated certificate I see that the certificate has

> Identity: badssl-fallback-unknown-subdomain-or-no-sni

which means SNI is failing. How can I get the server certificate of different subdomains of badssl.com? (I am using python 2.7.12)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
import ssl
hostname = "expired.badssl.com"
port = 443
conn = ssl.create_connection((hostname, port))
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
sock = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname=hostname)
certificate = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(sock.getpeercert(True))
```

Answer (score 20):

Searching for "Python ssl.get_server_certificate SNI" brought me easily to this answer. Although the OP himself answer is correct, I would like to provide a little more insight for future reference.

With some [hostname]s the fallowing call using Python 3.7:

```
ssl.get_server_certificate(("example.com", 443)
```

will complain with a traceback that ends with:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1045)
```

Doing some further investigation, making use of the `openssl s_client` utility, allows to discover that those same [hostname]s which made `get_server_certificate` to fail, also makes the fallowing command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443
```

to fail with this error:

```
SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error:s23_clnt.c:802
```

Note that the error message is similar to the one returned by the python code.

Using the `-servername` switch did the trick:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com
```

leading to the conclusion that the investigated hostname refers to a secure server that makes use of SNI (a good explanation on what that means is given by the [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) Wikipedia article).

So, switching again to Python and looking at the `get_server_certificate` method, examining the ssl module source ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ssl.py) for convenience), you can discover that the function includes this call:

```
context.wrap_socket(sock)
```

without the `server_hostname=hostname` key argument, which of course should mean that `get_server_certificate` cannot be used querying a SNI server. A little more effort is required:

```
hostname = "example.com"
port = 443

context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, port)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as sslsock:

        der_cert = sslsock.getpeercert(True)

        # from binary DER format to PEM
        pem_cert = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(der_cert)          
        print(pem_cert)
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me in Python 3.6. Extra thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It appears that, as of 2023, `get_server_certificate` [DOES include](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/90f1d777177e28b6c7b8d9ba751550e373d61b0a/Lib/ssl.py#L1436) the `server_hostname` argument