# PyOpenSSL - how can I get SAN(Subject Alternative Names) list

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I'm trying to find a way to get the list of SAN from a given certificate, however, I couldn't find anything in the pyOpenSSL documentation.

Any Ideas on how can I pull this data from the certificate?

Answer (score 9):

I found a way where we first check extension by name, and then, when "SAN" data found we get `str` representation and return.

```
def get_certificate_san(x509cert):
    san = ''
    ext_count = x509cert.get_extension_count()
    for i in range(0, ext_count):
        ext = x509cert.get_extension(i)
        if 'subjectAltName' in str(ext.get_short_name()):
            san = ext.__str__()
    return san
```

Comment: This is almost correct. A string comparison won't work as `ext.get_short_name()` is of type byte. I got that function working with the following hacky adjustment:


`if 'subjectAltName' in str(ext.get_short_name())`

Comment: possible depend on version, for me, string comparison works well, to be honest, I don't think that it should return bytes, but if you have this error -  then possible :)

Comment: I couldn't get it to return true until I made those changes. This was all done on python 3.6 with pyOpenSSL 18.0.0, likely a version issue :)

Comment: anyway str() not break anything, I've edited the answer, thanks.

Comment: I would modify your answer abit;  ext.get_short_name().decode('utf-8') to convert to a str and then ext.__str__().replace('DNS', '').replace(':', '') to remove "DNS" and ":" in the response string.

Comment: **Warning** the altnames are free form fields so a malicous third party could use `'DNS:altname1.net, DNS:altname2.net,, DNS:DNS:wtf'` for example

Comment: @Ashex or use "'subjectAltName' == ext.get_short_name().decode('utf-8')"

Comment: Why not str(ext)?

Answer (score 6):

PyOpenSSL [recommends](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html) using [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) as it provides a safer and better API. If you can install cryptography (it's a dependency of the `requests` library, so many projects already have it installed), here's how you get the SAN:

```
from cryptography import x509

# classes must be subtype of:
#   https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.ExtensionType
san = loaded_cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(x509.SubjectAlternativeName)
print(san)
```

Here's a full example of retrieving a cert from a host and printing its common name and SAN.

```
import ssl

from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

certificate: bytes = ssl.get_server_certificate(('example.com', 443)).encode('utf-8')
loaded_cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(certificate, default_backend())

common_name = loaded_cert.subject.get_attributes_for_oid(x509.oid.NameOID.COMMON_NAME)
print(common_name)


# classes must be subtype of:
#   https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.ExtensionType
san = loaded_cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(x509.SubjectAlternativeName)
san_dns_names = san.value.get_values_for_type(x509.DNSName)
print(san_dns_names)
```

Alternatively, if you're downloading a cert from a host, Python's built-in `ssl` library will parse the SANs for you (code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52464142/2958070)):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import socket
import ssl

hostname = 'www.python.org'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert
        cert = ssock.getpeercert()

subject = dict(item[0] for item in cert['subject'])
print(subject['commonName'])

subjectAltName = defaultdict(set)
for type_, san in cert['subjectAltName']:
    subjectAltName[type_].add(san)
print(subjectAltName['DNS'])
```

Comment: How would one extract just the value of common name?

In the representation "<NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.3, name=commonName)>, value='www.example.com')>],  print just 'www.example.com' ?

Comment: @YoloPerdiem , try `print(common_name[0].value)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @anatolii-chmykhalo answer

This returns the altnames for DNS, based on the string representation.

```
def get_dns_altnames(req: OpenSSL.crypto.X509Req):
    """
    Get DNS altnames from a X509Req certificate

    """

    extensions = (ext for ext in req.get_extensions()
                  if ext.get_short_name() == b'subjectAltName')

    dns_names = []
    for ext in extensions:
        for alt in str(ext).split(', '):
            if alt.startswith('DNS:'):
                dns_names.append(alt[4:])

    return dns_names
```

Answer (score -3):

I did some digging into it and I finally found something so if someone else will ever need the answer:

```
import OpenSSL

def extract_san_from_cert(cert_body):
    '''
    This function will extract the SAN (Subject Alt Names)
    from the certificate
    '''
    cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert_body)
    try:
        crt = cert.get_extension(6)
        data = crt.get_data()
        # ignore first 4 bytes and split in \x82\18 (,)
        san = data[4:].split('\x82\x18')
    except IndexError as err:
        # No SAN in the certificate
        san = []

    return san
```

Comment: This may not work as "get_extension" method may get another index to get SAN data, please check my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Also playing with bytes seems different depending on the case.

Comment: The bytes are not OK in that case, `\x18` is the length of your DNS name (and I'm guessing that `\x82` is the type)