# How to get more details on a requests.exceptions.SSLError?

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, ssl-certificate

When I request a URL with an expired HTTPS certificate I do not get a meaningful error from requests. Instead it gives me a cascade of "`ssl.SSLError: A failure in the SSL library occurred`".

See this example with https://expired.badssl.com/ :

```
>python
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get("https://expired.badssl.com/")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 362, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 386, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: A failure in the SSL library occurred (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 446, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='expired.badssl.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, 'A failure in the SSL library occurred (_ssl.c:1129)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='expired.badssl.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, 'A failure in the SSL library occurred (_ssl.c:1129)')))
>>>
```

`requests` is 2.24.0 and `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` says "OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020". I can not update the packages.

How can I get a meaningful error or error message that tells me that the certificate is expired?

Comment: As several other readers, I cannot reproduce the "SSL library failure". I'm getting the expected "expired certificate" error. I would try a direct connect (no Python) with `openssl s_client -connect expired.badssl.com:443` (as a shell command). It prints some info about the TLS handshake. Maybe you will be able to find a clue for the bug in it.

Comment: @VPfB For me the problem is 100% reproducible as long as OpenSSL version 1.1.1h is used as specified by the OP. After upgrading the OpenSSL library, an understandable certificate expiration message appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requirements:

- Environment: Python3.9.5 / requests 2.24.0 / OpenSSL 1.1.1h
- if a contact to a server fails, it should be determined whether the problem is an expired server certificate

Simplest solution would be to update the installed OpenSSL to, say, the current version `1.1.1n`, but even `1.1.1i` would be sufficient to get a message which contains `certificate has expired`. But updating the OpenSSL library cannot be done, as you mention in your post.

Alternatively, you can catch exceptions during a request and then explicitly check if the server certificate has expired.

To do this, you could, for example, take the `get_cert_for_hostname` function from a previous [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64505318/2331445) of mine and compare the `not_valid_after` field with the current date accordingly.

A simple, self-contained example might then look something like this:

```
import ssl
import requests
import platform
from datetime import datetime
from cryptography import x509


def get_cert_for_hostname(hostname, port):
    conn = ssl.create_connection((hostname, port))
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    sock = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname=hostname)
    certDER = sock.getpeercert(True)
    certPEM = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(certDER)
    conn.close()
    return x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(certPEM.encode('ascii'))


def is_cert_expired(hostname, port):
    cert = get_cert_for_hostname(hostname, port)
    return datetime.now() > cert.not_valid_after


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"Python version: {platform.python_version()}")
    print(f"OpenSSL version: {ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION}")
    print(f"requests version: {requests.__version__}")  #
    hosts = ['software7.com', 'expired.badssl.com']
    for host in hosts:
        try:
            requests.get(f"https://{host}")
            print(f"request for host {host} was successful")
        except BaseException as err:
            if is_cert_expired(host, 443):
                print(f"certificate for {host} expired")
            else:
                print(f"error {err} with {host}")
```

This would then log the following to the debug console:

```
Python version: 3.9.5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
requests version: 2.24.0
request for host software7.com was successful
certificate for expired.badssl.com expired
```

Comment: What a shame about the version but I will have to live with that until later updates. Thank you for the nice code example!

Answer (score 0):

This is normally how you would handle such a thing:

```
import requests
try:
    requests.get("https://expired.badssl.com/")
except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    print(f'oops! got the following SSL error: {e}')
```

And on my test machine the output contains `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired`

Since "certificate has expired" is not in your exception text, I suspect you have a bug in your version of something. `requests` 2.24.0 is not the latest version. Also, requests uses both urllib3 and certifi. Perhaps you should try:

`pip install --upgrade urllib3 requests certifi`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I am not able to update the libraries as I said in my question. Can you definitely identify my issue as a bug in a used package?