# Why is 'https://revoked.badssl.com/' and 'https://pinning-test.badssl.com/' returning 200 response using Python requests?

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, request, ssl-certificate

I'm working with Python requests and testing URLs from https://badssl.com/ certificate section and all the invalid URLs are returning errors except for https://revoked.badssl.com/ and https://pinning-test.badssl.com/. They are responding with `200 status codes`. I would like someone to explain why this is happening, despite the pages exhibiting errors such as `NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED` and `NET::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN` for the former and latter respectively.

```
import requests
def check_connection():
    url='https://revoked.badssl.com/' or 'https://pinning-test.badssl.com/'
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        r.raise_for_status()
        print(r)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print ("OOps: Something Else",err)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print ("Http Error:",errh)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print ("Timeout Error:",errt)

check_connection()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting an analog to "`NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED`" message because `requests` is just an HTTP request tool; it's not a browser. If you want to query an OCSP responder to see if a server certificate has been revoked, you can use the [`ocsp` module](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/ocsp/) to do that. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64505318/147356).

The answer is going to be similar for "`NET::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN`"; the `requests` module isn't the sort of high-level tool that implements certificate pinning. In fact, even the development builds of major browsers don't implement this; there's some interesting discussion about this issue in https://github.com/chromium/badssl.com/issues/15.