# SSL Errors for ssl.get_server_certificate on some websites but not on others

Tags: python, ssl, server, openssl, tls1.2

So I am trying to get some domains certificates using: (port is first retrieved from a nmap and secondly I try to use 443)

```
ssl.get_server_certificate((hostname, port))
```

But for some domains, like the following ones(only a couple of them): q1.insightsnow.redbull.com, mib-cdn.redbull.com, internalauditdb-uux-d.redbull.com, smg20.redbull.com, ssmg11-q.redbull.com, pm.redbull.com.
For this subdomains and many other ones I am getting a bunch of different errors:

- [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number
- timed out
- EOF occurred in violation of protocol
- [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure

I need to mention that for a lot of other subdomains (somewhere around 1000), everything works fine and I can get their certificate. But for ~200 of them I am getting the errors from above repeatedly and I can not find their source on the internet.

Do you happen to know why I can not use ssl.get_server_certificate on those website or where am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most if the sites here require SNI. It was a long standing issue that SNI was not done with `ssl.get_server_certificate` - see [ssl.get_server_certificate for sites with SNI (Server Name Indication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132025/ssl-get-server-certificate-for-sites-with-sni-server-name-indication) and [Python issue 36076](https://bugs.python.org/issue36076). It is finally solved with 3.10:

```
$ python3.8 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_server_certificate(("q1.insightsnow.redbull.com", 443)))'
...
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)


$ python3.10 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_server_certificate(("q1.insightsnow.redbull.com", 443)))'
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHnjCCBoagAwIBAgIRAPcBO50Fz5QaF+JxeyoL1vEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
gZUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdCMRswGQYDVQQIExJHcmVhdGVyIE1hbmNoZXN0ZXIxEDAO
...
```

For older Python versions see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132025/ssl-get-server-certificate-for-sites-with-sni-server-name-indication) on how to get the certificate without using `ssl.get_server_certificate`.

As for smg20.redbull.com and ssmg11-q.redbull.com - these sites do not seem to be reachable from the internet in the first place, i.e. they are also not accessible by other tools or the browser.