# FiwareLab - accumulator-server.py ImportError: No module named OpenSSL

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I can't run  accumulator-server.py in an Orion Context Broker instance.

```
sudo ./accumulator-server.py --port 1028 --url /accumulate --host ::1 --key --cert --pretty-print -v
```

**Error as:-**

> ImportError: No module named OpenSSL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602843/how-to-import-openssl-in-python

Comment: `pip install pyOpenSSL` should solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import OpenSSL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602843/how-to-import-openssl-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The requirements of the `accumulator-server.py` script can be installed using:

```
pip install pyOpenSSL flask
```

Take into account that the script, currently, only works on python 2.